# The .replace() is replacing occurrence in word

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, tags

I am having an input fields where the user can input tags

Say that user inputs "`xyz_DTL_D, John_D` " and is stored in `tagArr[]`.

I want to replace the input "`_D`" with the "" (empty string) value .so I wrote as :

```
 var dailycheck = "_D";
   for(var i = 0; i < tagArr.length; i++) {
        if(tagArr[i].indexOf(dailycheck) !== -1){
                        var str = tagArr[i].toString();
                        var finalTag =res.replace("_D" ,"");
                        $scope.tag[i] = finalTag;
                }
        }
```

The problem is it replaces the `_DTL` also with "" which is not expected.

Expected output: `XYZ_DTL , John`

Present output : `XYZTL_D , John`

Is there a way to just replace the expression "`_D`" and not the word starting from `_D` for all occurrences?

Suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks it worked

Answer (score 1):

> Say that user inputs "`xyz_DTL_D, John_D` "
>
> Expected output: `XYZ_DTL , John`

Looks like you want to replace only those `_D` which are **either at the end of string or just before `,`**.

Also, it seems that `"xyz_DTL_D, John_D "` is the output of `tagArr.toString()`

Try

```
var output = tagArr.map( s => s.trim().replace( /(_D)$/, "" ) ).join( "," );
```